# How to get a Vec of Structs out of dataframe?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

Suppose I've got

```
use polars::prelude::*;
pub struct Person {
    id: u32,
    name: String,
    age: u32,
}


let df = df!(
    "id" => &[1,2,3],
    "name" => &["John", "Jane", "Bobby"],
    "age" => &[32, 28, 45]
).unwrap();
```

How can I get a Vec of structs out in place of this fixed definition of `rows`?

```
let rows = vec![
    Person { id: 1, name: "John".to_string(), age: 32 },
    Person { id: 2, name: "Jane".to_string(), age: 28 },
    Person { id: 3, name: "Bobby".to_string(), age: 45 },
];
```

In case anyone's wondering why I ask, I'm trying to use leptos-struct-table with polars built in wasm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned the df into its constituent Series, zipped them together then mapped them into the Person

```
let rows:Vec<Person>=
    df.column("id").unwrap().i32().unwrap().into_iter()
    .zip(df.column("name").unwrap().str().unwrap().into_iter())
    .zip(df.column("age").unwrap().i32().unwrap().into_iter())
    .map(|((id, name), age)| {
        Person {
            id:id.unwrap(), 
            name:name.unwrap().to_string(), 
            age:age.unwrap()
        }
    })
    .collect();
```

Comment: Note that you can zip as many iters together as you like using [izip!()](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/macro.izip.html). For style reasons, you may prefer to separate the columns into their own variables and then izip them together.

Comment: You don't have to call `into_iter()` on the arguments to `zip`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`df.into_struct`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.into_struct). Please note that this feature is flagged under `dtype-struct` flag

```
polars = { version = "0.38.1", features = ["dtype-struct"] }
```

Here how the Rust code looks like:

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Person {
    id: u32,
    name: String,
    age: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let df = df!(
        "id" => &[1u32,2,3],
        "name" => &["John", "Jane", "Bobby"],
        "age" => &[32u32, 28, 45]
    )
    .unwrap();
    let foo: Vec<Person> = df
        .into_struct("StructChunked")
        .iter()
        .map(|row| Person {
            id: row[0].try_extract().unwrap(),
            name: row[1].get_str().unwrap().to_string(),
            age: row[2].try_extract().unwrap(),
        })
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", foo);
}
```

This will produce the following output

```
[Person { id: 1, name: "John", age: 32 }, Person { id: 2, name: "Jane", age: 28 }, Person { id: 3, name: "Bobby", age: 45 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with going through json (perhaps a tad expensive), it's pretty simple.

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::error::Error;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Person {
    id: u32,
    name: String,
    age: u32,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut df = df!(
        "id" => &[1,2,3],
        "name" => &["John", "Jane", "Bobby"],
        "age" => &[32, 28, 45]
    )
    .unwrap();

    let mut json = Vec::<u8>::new();
    JsonWriter::new(&mut json)
        .with_json_format(JsonFormat::Json)
        .finish(&mut df)?;
    let rows = serde_json::from_slice::<Vec<Person>>(&json)?;
    println!("{rows:?}");
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I don't want to serde it.