# How to generate Vec<T> in Rust from a Dataframe?

Tags: python, rust, python-polars, rust-polars, pyo3

I have a relatively long dataframe (10 columns, about a million lines) in Python. I want to pass it to Rust, process it and return another dataframe as output into Python.

It seemed convenient to construct a polars dataframe and pass it to Rust using pyo3. My question: what are the alternatives for creating Vec in Rust from a source dataframe?

Here is my `lib.rs`

```
use polars::frame::DataFrame;
use polars::prelude::*;
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3_polars::PyDataFrame;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct DummyData {
    foo: i64,
    bar: String,
}

#[pyfunction]
fn my_fun(pydf: PyDataFrame) -> PyResult<PyDataFrame> {
    let df: DataFrame = pydf.into();
    let vec_foo_i64: Vec<Option<i64>> = df.column("foo").unwrap().i64().unwrap().to_vec();
    let vec_bar_str: Vec<Option<&str>> = df
        .column("bar")
        .unwrap()
        .str()
        .unwrap()
        .into_iter()
        .collect();

    let mut dummy_vec: Vec<DummyData> = Vec::new();
    for (foo, bar) in vec_foo_i64.iter().zip(vec_bar_str.iter()) {
        // if any of the columns is null, skip the row
        if foo.is_none() || bar.is_none() {
            continue;
        } else {
            let dummy = DummyData {
                foo: foo.unwrap(),
                bar: bar.unwrap().to_string(),
            };
            dummy_vec.push(dummy);
        }
    }
    println!("{:#?}", dummy_vec);
    Ok(PyDataFrame(df))
}

#[pymodule]
fn pyo3_trial(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(my_fun, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Here is my python code.

```
import pyo3_trial
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": [1, 2, None],
        "bar": ["a", None, "c"],
    }
)
out_df = pyo3_trial.my_fun(df)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please review and understand the rules and guidelines *before* posting a question.  Soliciting opinions on "best practices" is off topic.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic

Comment: You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78140756/6699447)

Comment: Have you seen the plugin docs/tutorial? https://marcogorelli.github.io/polars-plugins-tutorial/ - https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/plugins/

Comment: I'd also encourage to post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for overall questions on code improvements.

Comment: based on my search row iteration is heavily discouraged but implementation feels less verbose and direct. @AbdulNiyasPM

Comment: thank you @jqurious, I haven't seen them before. Surely a highly potent feature but I couldn't relate how can I make use of it for my purpose.

Comment: It contains some "best practices examples" of how to process Series objects in Rust e.g. Section 5 has an example of using `ca.apply_to_buffer` specifically for String columns.